# Tell people that tag excerpts do not support formatting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

It happens quite often I see tag excerpts with lots of mark up like `**`, `[txt](link)` etc...

Please add a little box or something that tells people that wiki excerpts do not support formatting.

It will help avoid unnecessary [rejection of *minor* edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254664/why-was-my-useful-suggested-edit-to-this-tag-wiki-rejected).

Comment: @pnuts I honestly think it would just look to messy with all the formatting. I like it better with just straight text but that's just my opinion

Comment: I just got caught by this when trying to do my first tag wiki edit ever. Good thing I actually noticed after posting it.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with the next production build, we'll show a small note below the excerpt edit field:

> [image: (plain text only, no Markdown formatting]

Comment: Thank you. May we also tell people that plain URLs aren't supported? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370261/explicitly-note-that-tag-wiki-excerpts-edits-shouldnt-include-any-url

Comment: It's good that you made this change, like in this
_edit_ of the tag [character-set](https://i.imgur.com/tCTTN6u.png).
But did you forget to include the small note below the excerpt field when writing an excerpt _for the first time_?
~ * ~
See for example the tag for [tag:gomoku]!
– I would have expected to see _the small note_ between the two blueish lines in [this screen dump](https://i.imgur.com/7hFpyR3.png) (to the left of the mouse pointer).