# Tag excerpts guideline

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-excerpt

In addition to what "me how" requests in [Tell people that tag excerpts do not support formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254665/205955), I think it's a good idea to also put in informative box a reminder that purpose of tag excerpt is to help askers decide when to use specific tag and not to describe topic.

Observed phenomenon is that people tend to put systematics into tag excerpts which ends up with something like: `C++ is a widely-used, statically-typed, free-form, usually compiled, multi-paradigm, multi-level, imperative, general-purpose, object-oriented programming language`. Value of such boilerplate is zero. Noobs do not understand a word from it and if you understand these terms then you surely know what C++ is.

So, please remind users that tag excerpt is not wikipedia's `Infobox` and convince them that what they are going to put into tag excerpt should just help other users tag questions and not build encyclopedia.

Comment: Discussing almost the same problem on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302436/2790048. Please have a look.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the tag wiki interface can use some attention.

The *purpose* of a tag wiki excerpts (what they should contain) is a common source of misunderstanding. A lot of well-meaning users suggest really poor wiki excerpts, so I spend a lot of time on the opening days of a new site rejecting wiki excerpts that "define the word" rather than **"describe when the tag should be used."** Eventually the tag wikis start to improve, but the UI doesn't really help assure that will continue to be the case.

My early efforts to clarify the /review guidance for wiki excerpts didn't make the dev-resources cut, but but perhaps including some of the most common reasons I have to *reject* an excerpt (here in meta) will help create better guidance to help users get it right the first time: "tag excerpt guidelines".

Here are the most common tag wiki problems:

> **excerpt lacks usage guidance**
> Simply defining what a [tag] is does not make for a good wiki excerpt. Excerpts should describe ***why*** and ***when*** a tag would be used. See [**Writing tag wiki excerpts**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)
>
> **contains no additional information**
> Tag wikis saying "[tag] is for questions about [tag]" are not generally approved. Wikis should contain addition information. See [**Writing tag wiki excerpts**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)
>
> *<sub>(the next one applies more to the tag wikis rather than the excerpts)</sub>*
>
> **copied content**
> We prefer not to simply copy content available elsewhere in lieu of adding value to this site *specifically.* If a link helps support your original content, please see [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).