# Can we update C#'s excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-excerpt

I'm not the best at this, so I thought it would be best to post a discussion rather than directly editing the excerpt.

Current excerpt:

> C# (pronounced "see sharp") is a high level, object-oriented programming language that is designed for building a variety of applications that run on the .NET Framework (or .NET Core). C# is simple, powerful, type-safe, and object-oriented.

Problems I see:

1. For some reason, object-oriented is repeated.
2. Saying it's only object-oriented is very misleading, since it has *a lot* of functional features (the entire LINQ library couldn't exist without them, and that's only an example). It's much more a multi-paradigm language than an object-oriented one.
3. It's misleading saying it "runs on .NET and .NET Core". What about Mono and, currently in preview..., WebAssembly? I don't see the point of including this part at all.
4. It also supports the DLR, so it's as type-safe as you want it to be (I'm looking at you, *Office interop*)

For a starting point, I'd suggest something like the following.

> C# (pronounced "see sharp") is a high-level, multi-paradigm  programming language that is designed for building a variety of applications.

I don't think we need to say much more. We could add that a version-specific tag should only be used if the question is related to a feature introduced in that version.

---

We could go with something similar to what [Revision 36](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3624962/36) and [Revision 45](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3624962/45) had:

> C#  (pronounced "see sharp") is a multi-paradigm, managed programming language developed by Microsoft. Questions should include code examples, sufficient to reproduce the problem. Add extra tags, relevant to the used technology or library.

Comment: I agrree with the problems you pointed out. However your suggestion seems to general to me, since it could be used for every high-level, multi-paradigm language. Although C# is not restricted to them, .NET, type-safety (and object-oriented focus) *are* very important aspects of the language. Maybe these parts could be weakened. I wouldn't completely remove them.

Comment: excerpt should be guidance when to use the tag, yes it needs updating, but you need to tell me when to use the tag and when not to use it, not just some general stuff about C#

Comment: It has been edited 59 times already.  Meta is rarely a great place to find consensus about something so subjective even among the experts in a tag.  If you truly want to reset this back from scratch then it doesn't need anything more than "C# is a programming language".  The rest is pretty noisy elevator pitch, but somebody is going to add it back in less than a week :)  Consider to just get rid of the repetition.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yeah, but the current excerpt doesn't even help with saying when it should be used. How about something like my edit?

Comment: @Camilo I'm not an expert, but to me the include code stuff is wrong (let's hope Mark Amery) does not see that :), I have no experience in questions in that tag but a guidance would be something related to common problems in tagging, like "Always add this tag if your code is in C#, if the question is directly related to a specific version add version tag, please do only add tag of IDE if you have an IDE problem"

Comment: _but I'm just guessing what the common tagging errors are_

Comment: I will give you an example in a tag where I know what the problem is 1. They don't add main tag (If not no-one will probably see it) 2. They often add the tag even if not really related https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20975042, my english is not the best but a diligent Asker could get some guidance from that how to tag the question.

Comment: We run the risk we offend Jon Skeet if we get this wrong.

Comment: maybe just rollback to [revision 47](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3624962/47) and be done with it.

Comment: Wikipedias definition is much more accurate: `C# (pronounced C sharp) is a general-purpose, multi-paradigm programming language encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines.`

Comment: @0xaryan There was already problem for plagiarizing Wikipedia, so let's not repeat history: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302436/plagiarism-from-wikipedia-survived-for-3-years-in-the-c-tag-excerpt?rq=1

Comment: It is definitely not multi-paradigm. Having lambdas and closures thrown in does not make it a functional language. Static functions are still second class citizens, for example.

Comment: @jpmc26 "imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming", that's basically the definition of multi-paradigm, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm

Comment: The wiki also says it's designed to be OO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Design_goals It's self contradictory. It also reads like a marketing pamphlet that tries to throw in as many buzzwords as possible.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Also, only 2 of those are even language paradigms.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yeah, just like every language tag does

Comment: So if we want to improve the tag wiki, maybe we should tone down the marketing and focus on communicating some useful info?

Comment: The average programmer doesn't necessarily understand the meaning of "multi-paradigm language", while object-orientation is an established term.

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as an "object-oriented programming language", since object-orientation is a way to design programs. You can for example make C programs that are object-oriented, and you can make C# programs that are not.

There are however _languages with support for object-oriented features_.

Comment: @Lundin You're splitting hairs. Object orientation is utterly impractical and ill-advised in C. It's like saying you can write functional code in C#. Sure, if you practically build another language inside it. An OO language is a language that has support for it built in, making the paradigm doable in a practical way.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's not splitting hairs. If you know the slightest about OO, then you will know it's all about designing the rough layout of the program _before_ writing a single line of code in _any_ language.

Comment: That being said, it's fairly easy to do in C without much fuss, if you are competent. OO meaning private encapsulation, autonomous objects and a bit of inheritance. Having to call constructors/destructors manually is inconvenient and there's no RAII, but other than that, OO works ok in C. If you know what you are doing. If you don't... well, then don't use OO in C.

Comment: @Lundin The only way to attach functions to a data structure in C is via an explicit pointer. There is no privacy or actual binding of the function to the struct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/351745/1394393. That isn't an improvement over just calling the functions. It's clunky as all heck. As for, "it's all about designing the rough layout of the program before writing a single line of code in any language," no, this is just wrong. You yourself lay out (in the next comment) the common features that an OO language needs to support to make attempting the paradigm practical.

Comment: @jpmc26 The best way to do this in C is not to use function pointers, but to create some `object.h` and `object.c` with a list of functions that _is to be regarded_ as member functions. You interact with these through an _opaque pointer_ which provides the necessary private encapsulation and possibility of inheritance. Does it allow the syntax `object.func()`? No. Is that a requirement in OO design? No. For the same reason as C++ operator overloading isn't a requirement. OO is about program design, not about language syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problems with the [current excerpt at time of writing](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3624962/52):

- Reads like marketing material.
- Includes a lot of meaningless fluff ("building a variety of applications", "simple," "powerful")
- Does not explain when to use the tag

Additional problems with the older revision:

- C# is not multiparadigm. It's OO. The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) is the thing that's misleading. It has a few features that enable stuffing functions into variables, but it is definitely not a functional language. Functional languages are not imperative, and C# is definitely not equipped to avoid writing imperative code.
- Telling people how to write questions is out of scope for a tag wiki.

Suggestion to solve these problems:

> C# (pronounced "see sharp") is a high level, statically typed, object oriented programming language developed by Microsoft. C# code usually targets Microsoft's .NET family of tools and runtimes, which include the .NET Framework and .NET Core. Use this tag for questions about code written in C# or C#'s formal specification. Most questions also need a tag for the target .NET platform, such as [.net] (for the .NET Framework), [.net-core], or [.net-standard].

Reasoning:

- It's important to give the reader *some* brief description of what we're talking about.
- It's likely that people will be confused about the difference between .NET and C#, so this attempts to clarify that .NET is the tools and runtime while C# is the language.
- Tag wikis should indicate when to use the tag.
- Since most C# questions will be targeting a .NET platform and sometimes it matters which one, most C# questions will also need a tag indicating which platform is being targeted.

Possible improvements over this:

- I don't like using the word "platform." I don't think it's a term MS uses. Any info about what terms MS uses when discussing the different tool sets and runtimes is appreciated.

Things I notice in the [full wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info):

- The the bit about "multiparadigm" needs to be removed there.
- It claims `dynamic` enables "type inference," but that's not what it does. It disables static typing for that variable, preventing the compiler checks on type compatibility and member references.
- I don't know why there's a bunch of info about which versions introduced certain keywords and the features that correspond to them. Maybe it should just talk about the features themselves, without making it a change log? An SO tag wiki seems like a bad place for a change log.

Comment: I agree you should not put how to write questions, but excerpt is tag guidance, it should help a diligent user to tag correctly, inform about tagging practices in tag etc. Your suggestion does not give this information. If I need a definition of C# I will check Wikipedia not SO tag guidance.

Comment: *I would probably reject an edit like that with standard rejection reason "Does not provide guidance"*

Comment: @PetterFriberg That's fine. Someone apparently thought this was a good idea; I'm just trying to work with what we have. I'm honestly not sure what guidance you could give; you use the tag if you're programming in the language. If you have ideas, please post them; I'll gladly upvote if it's on point. As for checking Wikipedia, it's wrong in this case. Obviously written by people trying to market the language; it's the source of this "multiparadigm" nonsense.

Comment: Maybe *“[…] that run on .NET runtimes like .NET Framework and .NET Core”*?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Done, I think.

Comment: I don't think that you can tag format in an excerpt: you'll need to replace [tag:.net] with just ".net", etc.

Comment: @Cœur ....Seriously? Are you sure? Assuming it's correct: What is wrong with SO? You'd think that would've been implemented like 8 years ago.

Comment: @jpmc26 [Tell people that tag excerpts do not support formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254665/tell-people-that-tag-excerpts-do-not-support-formatting)

Comment: @jpmc26, much better, excerpt primary use is to popup and give you guiadance while adding tag to questions, hence links are not useful, they should instead just give a good tooltip.

Comment: @Cœur What are your thoughts on writing it as [.net] and [.net-core] to indicate these are tag references? Or is there a way to reword it so we don't have to mention the tag names explicitly? Is there a norm around writing tag names in excerpts?

Comment: @PetterFriberg See above.

Comment: @jpmc26 you can look at popular controversial tags like [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) to note that they indeed use [tagname] to refer to other tags.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm fine with [], whatever makes it easy to understand for a diligent user.

Answer (score 2):

I have suggested the following revision:

> C# (pronounced "see sharp") is a high level, object-oriented programming language developed by Microsoft. Questions should include code examples, sufficient to reproduce the problem. Add extra tags, relevant to the used technology or library.

Any improvements are welcomed.

Comment: The programming language is not "managed." The language just happens to be compiled to bytecode by Microsoft's tools. That's a property of the compiler and runtime, not the language.