# How important is basic guidance on when to use the tag in tag wiki excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

[The help center specifies:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)

> Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag

Personally I have always believed this is of fundamental importance (there is also an edit rejection reason specifically related to this).

The tag wiki excerpt pops up when a user selects the tag and therefore to me this is the moment for us to give some guidance (to diligent users). If needed, we should briefly explain when to add it, when not to add it, and maybe also tell them about some related tags.

***However*** I saw on [Can we update C#'s excerpt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374590/can-we-update-cs-excerpt/) that it was not considered (I had to comment quite a few times on different answers until it was).

***Furthermore***, the community is rejecting my edits in jasper-reports tags.

True my English is not perfect, but you can bet that I know how you should tag in [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) and I know about the common tagging problems:

- User adding only IDE ([ireport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ireport) or [jaspersoft-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaspersoft-studio)) tag, jasper-report contributors will not see it since we mostly filter just for main tag (we get only like 3–4 questions per day in this tag).
- In most cases you actually should not add an IDE tag since an IDE is not related ([Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876298/alex-k) most often will remove them).

If you trust me on this, please tell me why the community is rejecting:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20975042
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20975044

Is it my awful English? Is it that I'm confused about how important tag guidance in a "tag wiki excerpt" is?

<sup>Or maybe it's time for a plea of sanity?</sup>

Comment: I don't think your edit summary included enough about the reason you were deleting so much from the original. Also, reviewers are notoriously lazy :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I deleted to "take a stand"  *"what layouts can contain and what you can export to"* is according to me not useful when trying to define the tag and give usage guidance, were I wrong to delete it? Also note that since tag wiki the reviewers are people with experience on SO.

Comment: Well, you'd think those particular reviewers would be better (they all appear to have >10k). You might have been better off leaving the text around -- maybe move it after the tag guidance. People get really protective of tag wikis (as you can see from the discussion you cited), so apparently it's better to make them longer and longer. I'm with you on the purpose of tag excerpts; unfortunately, it seems the winds of change are upon us.

Comment: That said, maybe if you say you feel unwelcome by the edit rejections, they'll go through ;).

Comment: Leaving useless crap around.... never :P

Comment: What do you mean by *"use the tag in tag wiki excerpt"*? Isn't this about the body of the tag wiki? (Not rhetorical questions - only for clarification.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen It is "when to use the tag" in tag wiki excerpt,  but probably  I'm not understanding what you are telling me

Comment: @PeterMortensen if you mean tag wiki, no this question is only about tag wiki **excerpt**, I know I did tag it tag wiki, since there is no tag wiki excerpt tag, but still I think the excerpt can be considered within the general tag wiki.

Answer (score 12):

It's definitely not your English. Unfortunately, it's pretty common for the tag usage guidance to have nothing to do with when to use the tag. Very often the usage guidance is instead:

- A basic description of whatever language/framework/tool the tag is for only
- A marketing blurb
- A repeat of the first paragraph from the tag info itself
- Absolutely nothing

For example, here is a question being discussed on Meta: [Realtime web notification by using angular and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127662/realtime-web-notification-by-using-angular-and-php). Of all five tags, only angularjs tells the user when to use it and that almost certainly came about due to repeated discussions on meta about tag usage for Angular.

I suspect Heretic Monkey is right and that your edits got rejected because they removed content without explicitly pointing out in your edit summary that the content isn't useful.

> Is it that I'm confused about how important tag guidance in a "tag wiki excerpt" is?

I don't know. I personally think it's important but I don't know if that's commonly agreed upon. Like you said, it's actually shown to the user when adding tags but it could also be one of those things were it's assumed no one actually reads it.

Important or not, the edit was good and should have been approved.