# Previewing tag wiki excerpts

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

We should be able to preview tag excerpts when editing a tag wiki - Otherwise bad stuff will happen when formatting is used.  Tag wiki excerpts don't support all of (any?) markdown, but that isn't obvious.  In certain cases, this results in simply broken formatting like this:

[image: Tag wiki issues (Hopefully this uploaded right)]

Please allow previewing of the wiki excerpts - Make sure that it actually is formatted as it would be; I've noticed that [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20087359/revisions) actually formats it different from the way it would be (IE, it parses the markdown when it wouldn't be)

Comment: Re. "revisions actually formats it different from the way it would be" This issue was [raised two years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147828/suggested-edit-queue-renders-tag-wiki-excerpts-with-markdown-preview) and marked as `status-complete` last year. The "fix", however, only changed the view when improving excerpts in the suggested edit queue, and did nothing to fix the view in the edit history.

Comment: Related: [Tell people that tag excerpts do not support formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254665)

Comment: This is still an issue. I did not notice no markdown thing and [edit was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49790116/revisions)