# ok to put a link to CG.SE in the graphics tag info page?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

We've got a computer graphics site now in public beta ([visit!](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/)). Is it ok to add a link to it in the [graphics tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graphics/info) page?

And while we're all here, any other ideas to improve that info page? Some of the sentences don't make sense.

Comment: Loving the single paragraph there that describes "Computer Graphics"... Tempted to add a line about using graphic language, which is also used heavily when programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about policy, but I've done something like that before (in the excerpt, even) and nobody's complained.  For an example, see the [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) tag wiki excerpt:

> Cryptography covers, among other things, encryption, hashing and digital signatures. Cryptography questions not directly related to software development are better asked at crypto.stackexchange.com.

I'd say this is a win-win situation for SO and crypto.SE: SO gets fewer off-topic questions, crypto.SE gets more on-topic ones.  (Of course, I have no evidence of how much of an effect this actually has; even tag wiki excerpts are kind of easy to miss, not to even speak of the full wiki pages.)

Now, for specific advice, I'd say that mentioning the existence of (and linking to) other Stack Exchange sites in the *full tag wiki* should definitely be OK.  That's (one thing) the tag wikis are supposedly for: linking to other useful resources on the topic.

Also mentioning the other site *in the tag wiki excerpt* could be somewhat more controversial.  For crypto.SE, there's a fairly clear argument for it, since there's a whole bunch of theoretical crypto questions that are clearly on topic at crypto.SE, but are at best *very* marginally on-topic at SO.  In fact, I originally added the note after getting tired of regularly flagging off-topic crypto questions on SO for migration to crypto.SE.

Computer Graphics seems somewhat closer to SO's scope, so that such a clear area of non-overlap may be harder to find.  That said, I suppose you could still at least briefly mention that cg.SE exists, something like:

> <*insert basic tag description here*> There is also a separate SE site for this topic at computergraphics.stackexchange.com.

In any case, I agree that the current [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag wiki is pretty awful.  *Anything* you can do to clean it up is likely to be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a go. I think the excerpt is probably too long, but I can't preview that. :(

Comment: Seems OK to me, except that [Markdown doesn't work in tag wiki excerpts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254665/tell-people-that-tag-excerpts-do-not-support-formatting). (Yes, that kind of sucks, since it means we can't use links in the excerpt.) I've edited the excerpt so it's just plain text, and it looks OK for me. I think they increased the maximum excerpt length shown in the tooltip at some point, so it now matches the maximum length you can enter.