# Explicitly note that tag wiki excerpts edits shouldn't include any URL

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tag-excerpt

This post is a follow-up to *[Tell people that tag excerpts do not support formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254665/tell-people-that-tag-excerpts-do-not-support-formatting)*.

We now have this note when editing (since Jun 14 '17):

> (plain text only, no Markdown formatting)

Yet, I often see people attempting to include an URL in a wiki excerpt. So could we either prevent edits containing `http(s)://?` (pseudo regex notation) or remind editors with something along the lines of:

> (plain text only, no Markdown formatting, no URLs)

Comment: What's wrong with a URL you have to copy/paste? So long as it's relevant to the tag, it helps being more helpful than it harms user experience.

Comment: Many, many tag wikis include URLs, long lists of URLs, even. A URL isn't markdown.

Comment: @Booga the problem is that it's not rendered as a link, and non-clickable URLs that are actually plain text make the website look awful.

Comment: @CindyMeister The topic is about wiki **excerpts**, not wiki: the rendering and usage are different.

Comment: Right-clicking on a "non-clickable URL" gives you an option to open it in most browsers.

Answer (score -16):

URLs should be allowed.

They are generally more helpful than harmful, even without link formatting. I get that copy/paste for a URL isn't always ideal. I don't see any significant issue with allowing them as long as the URL isn't out of date, is relevant to the tag, and not spam/misleading/harmful.

Comment: If it isn't going to be clickable, then remove the protocol part: `https://asp.net` → `asp.net`, `https://python.net` → `python.net`.

Comment: But why do they need to be on the *exerpt*? It is meant to be a quick summary, so I shouldn't have to follow some link to read pages of information. They should go to the main tag-wiki.