# Tag popup text overflows due to URL addresses

Tags: bug, tags, tag-excerpt, popup

I just noticed that for some tag popups, the inside text is flowing out. I think it's because the URL address can't be wrapped:

> [image: Stack Overflow - TagPopup]

It's happening on Windows 10 and Chrome browser Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: What kind of madness is this? Square? Yellowish? Where are [the (red) free hand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/194457)?

Comment: Im on Windows 10 and Firefox 64.02 (64-bit) and that exact same tag wraps for me.

Comment: @HypnicJerk: You are right, it wraps on Firefox 64.0.2 (64-bit).

Comment: I don't see anything unusual. Can you mark it on the screenshot somehow? With freehand red circle?

Comment: Related: [Explicitly note that tag wiki excerpts edits shouldn't include any URL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370261/explicitly-note-that-tag-wiki-excerpts-edits-shouldnt-include-any-url)

Comment: @Cœur Note that currently [over 1000 tag excerpts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/967988/excerpts-with-links) do have links in them. That makes it reasonable to invest effort into fixing this, even though excerpts probably shouldn't have links.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth specifically for this tag, the chatroom is frozen for inactivity.

Comment: Great catch! This has been registered in the Bug Mines.Can you share what browser you are using?

Comment: @SaraChipps: As the post indicates, I'm using Chrome browser Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit), it occurs on IE also.

Comment: @SynerCoder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWhjA.png ... I just do not dare to edit ;)

Comment: Meta.SE cross-site post: [Long words in tag excerpts move outside the box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322730/289905).