# Tag excerpt for [google-apps-script] is messed up

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki

Tag's excerpt for [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) contains non-plaintext parts:

[image]

For reference: [Tell people that tag excerpts do not support formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254665/tell-people-that-tag-excerpts-do-not-support-formatting?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: IIRC Tag excerpts don't support markdown, and even if they did, the markdown for tags is `[tag:tagname]`

Comment: The edit window states "plain text only, no Markdown formatting" directly below the input box.

Comment: Now it's clear that question should be renamed to "Fix Google Apps Script tag excerpt"

Comment: Well... What's holding you back from fixing it yourself? You're free to edit tag excerpts, and put them up for review in the queue