# How to deal with plagiarized content in tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, plagiarism

While lurking in the "suggested edit" review queue (that Steward badge is sooooo shiny), I came across a couple of tag wiki edits that followed a certain pattern. They were adding a relatively significant chunk of text -- at least a couple of sentences -- to a tag wiki. Quickly googling this text demonstrated that they were clearly copied directly from other websites -- generally Wikipedia -- presumably in an attempt to get some rep from the edits.

Now, I was able to put "reject" votes in the edit queue, but other reviewers clearly approved them, and looking at the user's recent history there are others that I didn't catch in the queue.

Now I could just rollback, but clearly there's a deeper issue here.

What should I do? How can I flag a bad tag wiki edit? How do we deal with systematic bad behaviour of this kind?

Some of the edits:

- [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4921799)
- [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4921804)
- [string](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4921770)
- [JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4913658)

Comment: It's not only plagiarism, it's also making the tag descriptions worse cluttering them with irrelevant information. Maybe a lower limit on rep for editing tag wikis?

Comment: I like how you can see a Wikipedia [citation] marker in the Eclipse edit.  It *really is* copy and paste.  They didn't even try.

Comment: I see this has in fact [been brought up in the very recent past](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255740/wiki-edit-reviewers-are-not-catching-plagiarism).

Comment: I'm glad I rejected that now...

Comment: Hm I copy/pasted the tag [intuitionism](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/intuitionism/info) of math.stackexchange and I added the source link. And I don't see anything wrong in that... I didn't do it for the rep, that tag simply didn't have any description at all

Comment: @Dunno It's very different when there's attribution. And yours is at least useful...

Comment: @lonesomeday ah I must have misunderstood your question. Perhaps you should clarify that you don't mean copy/pasting per se, but when it adds pretty much nothing and is badly formatted.

Comment: @Dunno Well, I did write *plagarism* in the title. Since you put a source link in, it was *ipso facto* not plagarism! And that's what the problem is really about: how do we deal with systematic behaviour like this that isn't being adequately dealt with by the review system.

Comment: You instantly reject them by [performing a concurrent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2031322)! (only this will not lead to an edit ban)

Comment: Plagiarism is a pretty difficult accusation to make stick.  It is a fuzzy legal concept, but most recognize it as an unfair increase in reputation at the cost of the original creator.  Hard to make that apply to tag wikis, they cannot be voted for.  You might have a case for copyright infringement but again difficult to side-step the fair use clause.  Anybody whose product is covered by an SO tag is likely to favor an *accurate* representation, none better than his own words of course.  I have yet to hear about anybody getting upset about it.

Comment: @HansPassant: But a description on a vendor site is generally not written in the right style for a tag wiki.  Consider [the example lonesomeday linked above, from this perspective](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255740/wiki-edit-reviewers-are-not-catching-plagiarism#comment30102_255740)

Comment: [related, see accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254664/why-was-my-useful-suggested-edit-to-this-tag-wiki-rejected) and also [tag-wiki guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)

Comment: See also / related / dupe: [The tag wiki suggested edit review mechanism encourages low quality wiki content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254135/168868)

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that many people who review these things can't scour the internet for every source of plagarism. Easy to find things like Wikipedia might be more readily identified but... if it's good enough for Wikipedia, chances are it'll pass the smell test for the majority of reviewers. We can say reviewers should be held to higher standards but they obviously aren't holding themselves to higher standards.

What we really need is a way to mark them as plagarized that also includes a link to the source (much like we do with duplicate questions.)

Comment: I like this. A way to mark them to receive attention is good.

Comment: I use a simple test: looks good enough, was copied from somewhere else. Google up sentences, found? Reject.

Comment: These days, there are magical things called "search engines" that scour the internet *for you*. Checking whether content has been plagiarised wholesale requires about 10 seconds of effort; I don't buy the idea, even slightly, that it's unreasonable to expect reviewers to catch garden-variety plagiarism.